# CS50 - floating point exception arises when methods are called

Tags: c, debugging, cs50

I'm a new programmer trying to teach myself by doing the psets for CS50. I wrote the following bit of code, which works without a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


string vencipher(string text, string key)
{
    for (int i=0, j=0, n =strlen(text); i < n; i++,j++)
    {   
        int m = strlen(key);
        if (text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90 && key[j % m] >= 65 && key[j % m] <= 90)
        {
            text[i] = 65 + ((text[i] - 65) + (key[j % m] - 65)) % 26;
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90 && key[j % m] >= 97 && key[j % m] <= 123)
        {   
            text[i] = 65 + ((text[i] - 65) + (key[j % m] - 97)) % 26;
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 123 && key[j % m] >= 65 && key[j % m] <= 90)
        {
            text[i] = 97 + ((text[i] - 97) + (key[j % m] - 65)) % 26;
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 123 && key[j % m] >= 97 && key[j % m] <= 123)    
        {
            text[i] = 97 + ((text[i] - 97) + (key[j % m] - 97)) % 26;
        }
        else 
        {
            text[i] = text[i];
            j = j - 1;
        }    
    }       
    return text;
 } 

int keyvalidator(string text)
{
    int alphalen = 0;
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 123) || (text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90))
        {
            alphalen = alphalen + 1;
        }
    }
    if (alphalen == strlen(text))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}  

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || keyvalidator(argv[1]) != 1)
    {
        printf("That is not a valid secret key!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string secretKey = argv[1];
        string plainText = GetString();
        printf("%s\n", vencipher(plainText, secretKey));       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to try and split up vencipher into some different methods to try and improve the code's readability. This is what I did

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

string keycaseID(string key)
{
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(key); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (key[i] >= 65 && key[i] <= 90)
        {
            key[i] = 1;
        }

        else
        {
            key[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return key;
}

string setkeycase(string key)
{
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(key); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (keycaseID(key)[i] == 1)
        {
            key[i] = key [i] - 65;
        }
        else if (keycaseID(key)[i] == 0)
        {
            key[i] = key [i] - 97;
        }
    }
    return key;
}

string vencipher(string text, string key)
{
    for (int i=0, j=0, n =strlen(text); i < n; i++,j++)
    {   
        int m = strlen(key);
        if (text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90 && keycaseID(key)[j % m] == 1)
        {
            text[i] = 65 + ((text[i] - 65) + setkeycase(key)[j % m]) % 26;
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90 && keycaseID(key)[j % m] == 0)
        {   
            text[i] = 65 + ((text[i] - 65) + setkeycase(key)[j % m]) % 26;
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 123 && keycaseID(key)[j % m] == 1)
        {
            text[i] = 97 + ((text[i] - 97) + setkeycase(key)[j % m]) % 26;
        }
        else if (text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 123 && keycaseID(key)[j % m] == 0)    
        {
            text[i] = 97 + ((text[i] - 97) + setkeycase(key)[j % m]) % 26;
        }
        else 
        {
            text[i] = text[i];
            j = j - 1;
        }    
    }       
    return text;
 } 

int keyvalidator(string text)
{
    int alphalen = 0;
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 123) || (text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90))
        {
            alphalen = alphalen + 1;
        }
    }
    if (alphalen == strlen(text))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}  

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || keyvalidator(argv[1]) != 1)
    {
        printf("That is not a valid secret key!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string secretKey = argv[1];
        string plainText = GetString();
        printf("%s\n", vencipher(plainText, secretKey));       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The newer code compiles but when I run it I get a "floating point exception," which according to my research is the result of modulo divison by 0. I searched my code several times, and I can't find any instance of division by 0. I was wondering if someone could help me find my error and explain to me what's causing the floating point exception here.

Comment: Did it give you a line # where the error occurred?

Comment: Just add `if (m == 0) continue;` after line `int m = strlen(key);`

Comment: If you mean `'A'` then just write `'A'`, not `65`. Same for all the other numbers.

Comment: thanks, I'll edit that. I used the ascii values as a way of memorizing it and forgot to switch back.

@IIya -- That fixed the error but now the code isn't working. It doesn't encrypt anything it just outputs whatever the input is

Comment: @user42693, it means, that `string key` is empty. Try to use debugger to find the reason of it.

Comment: I have another question: I don't understand how m can be affected by either method. m is a function only of key... so the only way m should be able to be 0 is if secretkey itself was 0... but I'm not passing an empty string into the command prompt. Especially after moving all of the variables out of the for loops and defining them as soon as the methods are declared... yet I still get the division by 0 exception =(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also seen floating point exceptions on memory corruptions so that's the more likely scenario given there's not a `/` character anywhere in your code.

I will tell you *something* that you're doing wrong. By calling `keycaseID()` on the same string more than once (as you do in `setkeycase()`, you're guaranteed to end up with a string of all zeros (0 rather than `'0'`).

The first time it will convert all elements to either 1 or 0 depending on their case (and you therefore lose their original value). The second time, because they're either all `0` or `1`, they'll be less than 65 and therefore *all* set to 0.

Assuming your key is all alpha characters (upper or lower case), you can just use something like this to convert it into values 0 through 25:

```
for (int i = strlen (key) - 1; i >= 0; i--)  // needs string.h
    if (isupper (key[i]))                    // needs ctype.h
        key[i] -= 'A';
    else
        key[i] -= 'a';
```

or, even shorter:

```
for (int i = strlen (key) - 1; i >= 0; i--)  // needs string.h
    key[i] = toupper (key[i]) - 'A';         // needs ctype.h
```

Neither of those is perfectly portable since C doesn't mandate that `A-Z` are contiguous code points but, as long as you steer clear of weird non-ASCII environments, you should be fine :-)

Comment: "floating point exception" is reported by many systems for integer division by zero.

Comment: @Matt, I'll defer to you on that one since I'm unsure. But that would still require a `/` somewhere in the code :-)

Comment: Thank you! Can this also be fixed by initializing a variable in the function keycaseID() outside of the loop and setting it equal to keycaseID(key)? (So upping the scope?) I wanted to try to solve it with as few functions as possible (so without isupper) just to practice these kinds of details, but I will play around with ctype.h too. =)

Also I am guessing the problem is this in some way, since the % operator is probably floating division in the library if m is a string of all 0's then j % m would create the error.

Comment: @paxdiablo, `%` counts as division for this purpose. You can't do `%` without doing division "under the hood". In fact the CPU tends to have an instruction which will produce the quotient and the remainder in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be due to a problem with pointers, which we hadn't yet covered in class. What's going on here is string is defined by a pointer to the address in memory of the first char, and so when I tried to create a copy of string by initializing a new variable, I was instead creating a copy of that address and thereby editing both the original input string and the new copy since they share the same memory address.

Because of this the length of m was indeed 0, since keycaseID was modifying the values at the memory address of key, thus wiping key and causing setkeycase to return the empty string.